# AWSSecurityTokenService Status Code 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using AWS's JAVA SDK 1.12.261.
The AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard part is in error.
I created a Role.
Is there something wrong with the configuration?

User Associated Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/sts-role"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/test"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Java Code

```
AWSCredentials credentials1 = new BasicAWSCredentials(OssConfiguration.accessKey, OssConfiguration.secretKey);
        AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials1);
        String region = OssConfiguration.region;

        AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder stsClientBuilder = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                .withRegion(region);

        AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = stsClientBuilder.build();
```

Error

```
User: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/test is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:s3:::s3-name/ (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx; Proxy: null)",
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS SDK for Java V1 is not best practice. AWS recommends using [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html).

*The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at runtime.*

You can find STS operation examples in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html). Here is AssumeRole.

[Assume a role with AWS STS using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sts_example_sts_AssumeRole_section.html)

When you run this code, make sure you create a Role that you want to assume. Then define a Trust Relationship in the AWS Console.

Here is the full example. I just ran it and it works!

```
// snippet-start:[sts.java2.assume_role.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.StsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.AssumeRoleRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.StsException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.AssumeRoleResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.Credentials;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Locale;
// snippet-end:[sts.java2.assume_role.import]

/**
 * To make this code example work, create a Role that you want to assume.
 * Then define a Trust Relationship in the AWS Console. You can use this as an example:
 *
 * {
 *   "Version": "2012-10-17",
 *   "Statement": [
 *     {
 *       "Effect": "Allow",
 *       "Principal": {
 *         "AWS": "<Specify the ARN of your IAM user you are using in this code example>"
 *       },
 *       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
 *     }
 *   ]
 * }
 *
 *  For more information, see "Editing the Trust Relationship for an Existing Role" in the AWS Directory Service guide.
 *
 *  Also, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 *  For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 *  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class AssumeRole {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <roleArn> <roleSessionName> \n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    roleArn - The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the role to assume (for example, rn:aws:iam::000008047983:role/s3role). \n"+
            "    roleSessionName - An identifier for the assumed role session (for example, mysession). \n";

        //if (args.length != 2) {
         //   System.out.println(usage);
       //     System.exit(1);
      //  }

        String roleArn = "arn:aws:iam::814548047983:role/s3role" ; //args[0];
        String roleSessionName = "mysession110" ; // args[1];
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();

        assumeGivenRole(stsClient, roleArn, roleSessionName);
        stsClient.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[sts.java2.assume_role.main]
    public static void assumeGivenRole(StsClient stsClient, String roleArn, String roleSessionName) {

        try {
            AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
                .roleArn(roleArn)
                .roleSessionName(roleSessionName)
                .build();

           AssumeRoleResponse roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
           Credentials myCreds = roleResponse.credentials();

           // Display the time when the temp creds expire.
           Instant exTime = myCreds.expiration();
           String tokenInfo = myCreds.sessionToken();

           // Convert the Instant to readable date.
           DateTimeFormatter formatter =
                   DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT )
                           .withLocale( Locale.US)
                           .withZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() );

           formatter.format( exTime );
           System.out.println("The token "+tokenInfo + "  expires on " + exTime );

       } catch (StsException e) {
           System.err.println(e.getMessage());
           System.exit(1);
       }
   }
   // snippet-end:[sts.java2.assume_role.main]
}
```